# <fieldset> outside of the <div>

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have got a problem with a mark up.

It happening when I resize browser window.

Here is my code (ASP.NET):

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelGrid" runat="server" CssClass="frame">
 <fieldset class="fs">                        
   <legend> 
     <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="LALALA"></asp:Label>
   </legend>
  </fieldset>
</asp:Panel>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The border was outside of the Panel.

If I use this code(without `<fieldset>`):

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelGrid" runat="server" CssClass="frame">

   <legend> 
     <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" Text="LALALA"></asp:Label>
   </legend>

</asp:Panel>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

How can I must write the CSS class ("fs"), if I want to use `<fieldset>`?
Thanks!

P.S My class code:

```
.frame
{


    margin: 1px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid Navy;

    background-color: White;
    font-size: 9pt;

    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #1A3457; /* Валидное свойство CSS 3 тень*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #1A3457; /* Safari, Chrome */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px #1A3457; /* Firefox */
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: The question is really not clear enough to understand your problem.

Comment: What's your current CSS? Can you provide a simple example in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @freebird agreed, provide some markup and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css:

```
.fs {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Did you reload the page with `F5` or `CTRL F5`?

Comment: Yes. maybe Firefox using other properties?

Answer (score 4):

The `Panel` control is capable of rendering `fieldset` tags on its own, you only have to specify the [`GroupingText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.groupingtext.aspx):

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" GroupingText="your fieldset group">
    </asp:Panel>
```